# How to create two databases in django app with docker-compose

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I connect can to my pgadmin with `db1` but impossible to connect in with `db2`. I got this error `Unable to conect to server: ...` (see picture). I have seen some post but none of them resolve my problem.[image]

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    entrypoint: /code/docker-entrypoint.sh
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db1
      - db2
    volumes:
      - .:/code
  db1:
    container_name: database1
    image: postgres:14.4
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
  db2:
    container_name: database2
    image: postgres:14.4
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5433:5433"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:6.20
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - ./pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - '8001:80'
    depends_on:
      - db1
      - db2
      - web
```

Comment: Are you sure db2 is running on port 5433 inside the container?

Comment: Yes, I got this                                                                                                           
  5432/tcp  Not bound and 
  5433/tcp  0.0.0.0:5433

Comment: It doesn't look like you're told the PostgreSQL process to use the alternate port.  You should use the standard port 5432 for connections between containers and as the second `ports:` number for that database.

Comment: @DavidMaze, sorry, I am not sure to understand

Comment: In PGAdmin, use port 5432 as the port number.

Comment: I have done this. It works with success. But I don't understand since in the docker-compose file the mapped port is 5433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with db2 is the port

```
db2:
    container_name: database2
    image: postgres:14.4
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5433:5433" - this port should map default postgres db : 5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

change to

```
db2:
    container_name: database2
    image: postgres:14.4
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

As PGAdmin is running within the docker network, all you need to do is change the port to `5432` in PGAdmin dashboard. As you (PGAdmin) are already in the same network (docker network) with DB2, docker can resolve the host (db2) and port directly, hence no need to use the port map:

[image]

But if you want to expose the DB2 to outside of docker network, then you can change the port number in compose (but it is not needed for PGAdmin):

```
db2:
    ...
    ports:
      - "5433:5432" #<-- 5432 is the port of the container, 5433 is port of the host ie localhost:5433
    ...
```